# Integrate Spring security java configuration with xml configuration-based project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security, servletcontextlistener

I am new in spring framework and right now i am struggling to integrate an example of spring security java-based configuration with an existent xml-based project configuration.
I have included the following lines into the web.xml in order to link the security config to xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MobileDrive_Maven</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>    
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.websystique.springmvc.security</param-value>
        <!-- <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value> -->
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

What am I missing because I am getting an error that it could not autowire stuff inside(Injection of autowired dependencies failed)?